# User should be on sudo group, but it is not

Tags: permissions, sudo, users

I'm using my father's computer (named SandroPC) and only his user (sandro) was the administrator. I created a user for myself (guilherme) and tried adding it to sudo group, but a weird thing has happened:

When I log in on my user, it doesn't appear to be on sudo group:

```
guilherme@SandroPC:~$ groups
guilherme
```

And, if i do a su - guilherme, it appears to fix the problem:

```
guilherme@SandroPC:~$ su - guilherme
Password:
guilherme@SandroPC:-$ groups
guilherme sudo
```

And, on /etc/group, the user is listed as sudo:

```
guilherme@SandroPC:~$ cat /etc/group | grep sudo
sudo:x:27:sandro,guilherme
```

This problem does not happen when I log into his user, it is instantly on sudo group.

Is this the expected behaviour? If not, how do I fix the problem? If it is, is there a work-around for this?

I'm sorry for my bad english, as it is not my main language. Thank you!

Comment: Please Edit ( https://askubuntu.com/posts/1157903/edit ) your post and show us `/bin/ls -l /etc/group`. Did the first login happen before the file was edited? Group membership is assigned at `login` time, but see `man newgrp`. What does `id` show?